# What is the pictured component?

Tags: identification, motherboard

Does anyone know which SMD is shown in the picture below? It's labelled with 20J on its body and PU5004 on the PCB. Online research didn't bring me anywhere. I tried to look up motherboard schematics from similar laptop models but couldn't find anything helpful.

[image]

This component blew up through local water damage which happened in close proximity to the component. Quite frustrating to lose the whole motherboard because of an otherwise easily replaceable SMD. It's a motherboard from HP and has the spare part number L53570-601.

[image]

Above is another picture of the component with its surranding.

Comment: So how do you know this component needs replacing, and that it is the only broken component? If the fault is elsewhere a new component will also get broken until the actual fault is fixed.

Comment: @Justme the hole in the top is a pretty clear answer to your first question ...

Comment: @brhans That could be anything like a dot made with black marker pen. But yes, it could be a blown chip too.

Comment: @Justme, I spent a good hour visually inspecting the board.

Comment: @andrebienemann I understand, but water does not blow up components. If water caused a problem that this component blew up due to overvoltage or overcurrent condition, other components can also be damaged but it is just not visible. The overvoltage condition may still be present. So even if you do get an answer what component this is, the laptop may not get fixed by replacing this component. If you want it repaired, have it serviced by a repair shop with skilled technicians and service manuals for troubleshooting.

Comment: HP only earned US$5.3 billion last year, so they really need your support. Please throw away the laptop that wasn't adequately waterproofed and buy another one.

Comment: @andrebienemann just be prepared, that not all damage is visible on the components.

Comment: did you find that part? I have simiilar issue, this part gets hot as soon as I plug in charger. It is also labeled as PU5004, but has 20L written on it.

Comment: @AdamGrufík, I stopped my research. So, I didn't find the part. However, a friend of mine suggested that it must be a dual MOSFET and could be identified by its context in terms of voltage on its pins and linked components.